# nested vectorized openmp loops with multiple lines of code in inner-most loop

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I was wondering if it is valid to use an opemp `simd` construct to collapse multiple nested loops, where
the code in the inner-most loop first calculates a number of indices (as shown below) and then those indices
are used to modify a multidimensional array (as shown below). In other words would the lines labelled `I1-I4`
below be all vectorized? In all the openmp examples I have seen there is always a single variable whose result gets
vectorized. Would the below code be considered valid? Thanks

```
for(std::size_t a=0;a<A;a++)
{
  #pragma omp simd collapse(3)
  for(std::size_t b=0;b<B;b++)
  {
    for(std::size_t c=0;c<C;c++)
    {
      for(std::size_t d=0;d<D;d++)
      {
        std::size_t idx1 = c*B + b; //I1
        std::size_t idx2 = d*(B*C) + c*B + b; //I2
        std::size_t idx3 = d*(E) + c*F + b; //I3
        W1[idx1][idx3] += W1[idx1][a]*W2[a][idx3]; //I4

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely valid OpenMP code. Depending on the compiler, and the target architecture, the results of compiling it may change, but at least some compilers will definitely vectorize it. Because the indices are likely non linear, it will only vectorize well on a platform with both gather and scatter instructions, but it’s valid regardless.